# Start h5Validate Script by pressing on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the h5Validate Script to validate my form.
everything works fine.

Here is an input field:
`<input id="ort" name="ort" type="text" data-h5-errorid="error-message"     class="field text fn" >" required size="8" tabindex="1" />`

And here is the error message:
`<section class="errors"><p id="error-message"><span>Bitte füllen Sie die markierten Felder aus.</span></p></section>`

The Problem is that the error message occurs each time i leave an input field and if it's empty.

Is there a possibility that the message occurs after pressing submit.??
Then the user fill all the inputs and press submit again.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the events that trigger form field validation. To do so, turn off `focusout`, `focusin`, `change`, `keyup`.

However, **I strongly discourage changing the defaults**. The default settings for h5Validate were set by watching users interact with a shopping cart used my millions of monthly users. We took live video recordings of users interacting with the shopping cart, and surveyed 1,000 users, and fine-tuned the error message triggers to produce **the best user experience we could**.

We found that when you wait for the user to click submit, they **frequently have a hard time figuring out which field needs to be fixed** -- even with in-line error messages right next to form fields. This problem is particularly **bad on small screens** (such as mobile), or users with large fonts that force them to scroll to click submit.

Doing the validation inline when they move to the next field alerts the user right away that there's something that needs to be corrected before they try to submit the form. Validating in realtime as the user interacts with the form improved user's success rates by double digit percent points, which made a difference of millions of dollars in that particular shopping cart, and resulted in much happier users.

By default, h5Validate will also run the form validation when the user submits the form.